# When booking a room how to make already taken dates unclickable in jQuery datepicker?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

once more
I am writing a jQuery script for my hotel asp.net MVC 3 application.
I would like to make drop down calendar in jQuery so that already reserved dates for particular room are not clickable. 
That means that first I have to read taken dates from database and then, somehow, read it in jQuery script before showing appropriate calendar for a room reservation date.

Do I need to learn jQuery for all this, if not, how to do it? Is Ajax needed for database retrieval of appointed dates?
Can you please help me?

thank you very much

P.S. If I need to learn jQuery (and/or Ajax), can you give me some quality resource hints? Thanks

Comment: I guess everyone is at the bar wright now;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this from google
[jQuery UI DatePicker: Disable Specified Days](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days)

You can wrap this code within a JS function and pass the date list to it (something like)

```
    function ShowDatePicker(dateList)
{
var disabledDays = dateList;

/* utility functions */
function nationalDays(date) {
  var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
  //console.log('Checking (raw): ' + m + '-' + d + '-' + y);
  for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
      //console.log('bad:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y + ' / ' + disabledDays[i]);
      return [false];
    }
  }
  //console.log('good:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y);
  return [true];
}
function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
  var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
  return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
}

/* create datepicker */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#date').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2010, 5, 31),
    dateFormat: 'DD, MM, d, yy',
    constrainInput: true,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
  });
});
}
```

Comment: Try to give a summary here (with some code), just in case the link goes down ;).

Comment: I also found something similar , but like yours, it is working on a static data. It would be better if I could get dynamically data, from DB. Here is my version in google: http://tokenposts.blogspot.com/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html

Comment: But this is only for weekends etc., I would like to make it unclickalbe for some specified days from database?

Comment: I have found this: http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/09/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specified-dates/ but there is still no ajax included.